# Sorting Datastore and Enhanced Datagrid in Dojo

Tags: sorting, datagrid, dojo

I need to keep the datastore sorted. When I add sortInfo datastore gets sorted for the first time. When I add another item it goes as last element. Therefore datastore is not in sorted order.

Even if i change the value of the cell in column that needs to be sorted also the order gets disturbed.

How to keep the datastore in dojo be sorted?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to call a save() on the store to commit your changes for your sort order to be reflected.